# WebApplicationException v/s ExceptionMapper in RESTful (Jersey) Web Service

Tags: java, rest, exception, jersey

I'm learning REST web service. I need some clarification on handling custom exception in `Jersey`. By using `WebApplicationException` and `ExceptionMapper` you can `throw` custom `Exception`. My question is in which scenario we have go for `WebApplicationException` and `ExceptionMapper`. What are the differences between them?

I've gone through with some tutorial, I found that `ExceptionMapper` is like Generic.

```
@Provider
class MyWrapper implements ExceptionMapper<MyPojoClass>
{
}
```

One more difference is that,

Because of `@Provider` `Jersey` will catch this exception only by default, if any other exception occurs also.

Is there any other differences?

**MyExceptionMapper.java**

```
package com.katte.galaxe.exception;

import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response.Status;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.ExceptionMapper;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;


public class MyExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<MyCustomException>
{

@Override
public Response toResponse(MyCustomException errMsg) {
    ErrorMessage msg = new ErrorMessage(errMsg.getMessage(),1100);
    return Response.status(Status.NOT_FOUND)
            .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
            .entity(msg)
            .build();
}
}
```

**MyWebApplicationException.java**

```
package com.katte.galaxe.exception;

import javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response.Status;

public class MyWebApplicationException extends WebApplicationException{

private static final long serialVersionUID = -5788907118191114665L;

public MyWebApplicationException(ErrorMessage msg) {
    super(Response.status(Status.NOT_FOUND)
            .entity(msg)
            .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
            .build());
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

WebApplicationException and ExceptionMapper are not meant to be compared as they serve different purpose. Instead they are meant to be used together for a better response strategy.

Imagine a case wherein an exception is encountered while serving a request. Let's say you encountered a SQLException while accessing a database. In this case one can make use of ExceptionMapper to map SQLException with an appropriate 5xx response instead of propagating the original exception to the end user.

> **WebApplicationException**
>
> Runtime exception for applications.
>
> This exception may be thrown by a resource method, provider or StreamingOutput implementation if a specific HTTP error response needs to be produced. Only effective if thrown prior to the response being committed.
>
> **ExceptionMapper**
>
> Contract for a provider that maps Java exceptions to Response.